# Not able to control the execution of code Inside fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am calling fetch Inside a function but the statements are not being executed the way I want it to.

```js
getHubspotData('https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/paged?hapikey=demo&properties=dealname&properties=dealstage&properties=closedate&properties=dealtype&properties=type&properties=hubspot_owner_id&properties=amount&properties=notes_last_updated&includeAssociations=true');

function getHubspotData(url){
    console.log("URL: "+url);
        fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
    .then(function(data) {
console.log("Inside Fetch");
    })
    console.log("Outside Fetch");
}
```

The statement Outside Fetch executes first followed by Inside Fetch.

How can I make the code Inside Fetch execute first, such that the Output would be

```
Inside Fetch
Outside Fetch
```

Comment: You can wrap the `console.log("Outside Fetch")` in a subsequent `then`.

Comment: or make the entire thing async and use await

Comment: `fetch` is an asynchronous operation, so the code after it will execute immediately before its promise is resolved. What is the use case of you having code *after* the fetch function?

Comment: Library? It's vanilla JS. It looks like fetch is throwing some error (CORS?). Try adding some catch to the sequence to control it.

Comment: @SergioTx please forget I asked that

Comment: this is (not so obvious) attempt **to return value from asynchronous function**. Hardly possible.

Comment: @Terry Calling a 2nd Fetch Function after the 1st Fetch Function completes.